# Custom format to link react-quill

Tags: reactjs, quill, react-quill

I am trying to create a custom format for links in react-quill. I will attach the working code at the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-mendel-gj4fqx?file=/src/index.js).

```js
class LinkBlot extends Inline {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create();

    node.setAttribute("href", value);

    if (/^(https?:)?\/\//.test(value)) {
      node.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
      node.setAttribute("rel", "noopener noreferrer");
    }

    return node;
  }

  static formats(node) {
    return node.getAttribute("href");
  }
}

LinkBlot.blotName = "link";
LinkBlot.tagName = "a";

Quill.register("formats/link", LinkBlot);
```

There is a problem, after adding a link I can't open it for editing, as it happens without custom formatting.
How can i fix this problem ?